# Simplest way to render a 3D scene to an image file

Tags: python, 3d, mesh

I have a 3D scene (essentially a VRML file with one big IndexedFaceSet). I want to render the scene once into an image file. The image file will serve as a preview to the user, who will then be able to open the scene in a 3D viewer ([`X3DOM`](http://www.x3dom.org/) - it's a great library).

I know the camera position, direction and field-of-view angle necessary for the preview, as well as the lighting.

The preview image will be prepared offline on the server. Everything else on the server is written in Python, and I'd rather not introduce another language to the mix.

I tried Matplotlib, but couldn't figure out how to perform proper shading and lighting there. I don't want to start a browser instance on the server and let X3DOM do the heavy lifting. I guess I can use PyOpenGL to render the scene once and save it to a file, but I'm hoping there's an easier way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could install blender, import and render through that but it is probably overkill.

OpenGLContext would probably provide all that you need: [pyOpenGL](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/context/) it seems to be quite well documented and reasonable to use and seems to support the import of VRML.

If you need a higher resolution then you can make use of [YaFaRay](http://www.yafaray.org/) but I found it a lot harder to see if VRML import was supported directly or not.

Comment: Blender is indeed an overkill. OpenGLContext, on the other hand, is a great idea. I should have thought of that myself! I'll try it and see if it works.

Comment: This is embarrasing... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331694/render-a-scenegraph-with-pyopengl

Comment: OK, I managed to display it properly. Now I need to save the resulting image to a file.

Comment: Excellent, the OpenGLContext class *already* has an OnSaveImage function which saves the rendered image to a file. This works! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it & pleased to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at OpenSceneGraph? It's intended to be used with c++ but there are [3rd party bindings](http://trac.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg//wiki/Community/LanguageWrappers) available for Python I believe, although maturity of those bindings may vary (that said it may be good enough to read a VRML and write an image).