# Render a SceneGraph with PyOpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, scenegraph, openglcontext

I'm using OpenGLContext to load a VRML file into a SceneGraph object. Unfortunately, for the life of me I can't find any example showing how to render the SceneGraph.

I've created a context with `testcontext.getInteractive()`, but now what? How do I render a SceneGraph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite poorly documented. All that needs to be done is create a context class and set its `sg` field, like so:

```
def MyContext(BaseContext):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.sg = ... load your scene graph here ...

    def OnRender(self, mode):
        return
```

And that's it, the scene is rendered properly.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at:
http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/context/tutorials/shader_1.xhtml
It steps you through the process with some thorough explanations.

Comment: I would rather not create the shaders and handle the lighting myself. I did find I can place a scenegraph in `self.sg`, but right now all I see is a blank scene. I think it's because the camera isn't located properly, I'll try to fix it.